# Is generalized pigeonhole search known to be no harder than PPP?

Tags: search-problem

Consider the TFNP search problem

> Given a positive integer $t$ in unary, positive integers $M$ and $N$ (in binary), and a
>   
>   function from $\{0\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.04 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}3,...,\hspace{-0.02 in}M\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.04 in}2\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}M\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$ to $\{0\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.04 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}3,...,\hspace{-0.02 in}N\hspace{-0.05 in}-\hspace{-0.04 in}2\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}N\hspace{-0.05 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$ (as a circuit),
>   
>   find $\: \operatorname{min}(t,\hspace{-0.04 in}\lceil M/N\hspace{.02 in}\rceil) \:$ distinct inputs that map to the same output.

.

That problem is clearly hard for the class [PPP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppp). $\:$ Is that problem known to be *in* PPP?

Comment: Note that if $M = N$ then $\min(t,\lceil M/N \rceil)\leq 1$ i.e. the problem asks for 1 distinct input (the problem is immediately solvable).

Comment: I propose to first work on the $M=2N+1$ case. Apparently in CS hash triple collisions are much harder to find than simple collisions, though this does not necessarily imply anything for your question. I would guess that this problem cannot be reduced to PPP, and would be related to PPA-3 the same way as PPP is related to PPA. In variants of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem when one wants a triple collision, you also have to use mod 3 instead of parity arguments. Very nice question, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please see the comments below by Emil Jeřábek,** so I am not that sure anymore that the problem is harder.

No, it is not known but it is harder than PPP :)

Here I focus on the $M=2N+1$ case, so $t=3$, that is, we want $3$ inputs that map to the same output. In Papadimitriou's seminal paper "On the Complexity of the Parity Argument" he defined PPA-3 similarly to PPA as the search problems reducible to the argument "If in a bipartite graph a node has degree not a multiple of 3, then there is at least another such node."

Let me define here PPAD-3 in a way similar to PPAD as the search problems reducible to the argument "If in a balanced, directed bipartite graph $(A,B;E)$ there is a node in $A$ whose outdegree is not $2$ or whose indegree is not $1$, then there is at least another such node in $A$ OR there is a node in $B$ whose outdegree is not $1$ or whose indegree is not $2$."

Just like PPAD$\subset$PPP, you can show that PPAD-3 is a subset of the problem you have defined. Unfortunately this is all the evidence I can give you as (as far as I know) PPA-3 has not been investigated much and no oracle separation results are known for it, though I don't think it would be hard to obtain some. Papadimitriou defining it as a separate class should be enough evidence that there is a good chance that they differ.

Comment: I find this answer fairly unconvincing. Yes, PPAD-3 is likely incomparable with PPAD, but I see no reason why it shouldn’t be included in PPP. (IOW, counting mod 2 and counting mod 3 are equally well reducible to counting.) The problem in the OP may turn out not to be in PPP as this class is generally nasty (e.g., unlike other Papadimitriou’s classes it is not known to be closed under Turing reductions), but if so, I would expect a different reason than you state.

Comment: @Emil: Of course you might be right, but I would guess that there is an oracle separation between any of the above classes.

Comment: Do you have any particular idea in mind for a construction of an oracle separating PPAD-3 from PPP that does not apply to PPAD-2? I’m not aware of any oracle separation results for the pigeonhole principle that would work for one prime and not for another.

Comment: Actually, I’m struggling with your definition of PPAD-3. First, the search problem is not even total unless one requires $|A|=|B|$. Second, is there an a priori bound on the in- and out-degrees ($\le2$), or alternatively, do you count them modulo 3? Otherwise I don’t see how is this meant to be a directed version of Papadimitriou’s PPA-3.

Comment: In fact, assuming the graph is given using similar conventions as in Papadimitriou’s paper (basically, a circuit computing to a given node the set of its neighbours) and $|A|=|B|$, your PPAD-3 is in PPP: if $a$ is the given special node from $A$, then depending on whether $\deg_i(a)=0$, $\deg_i(a)>1$, $\deg_o(a)>2$, or $\deg_o(a)< 2$, use the right-to-left (in the first two cases) or left-to-right (otherwise) edges of the graph to construct an injection $|B|\to|A|-1$, $|A|\to|B|-1$, $2|A|+1\to|B|$, or $2|B|\to2|A|-1$ (respectively).

Comment: @Emil: Unfortunately I cannot understand the last sentence in your comment. I think the interesting case is when $deg_o(a)=3$. The edges from $B$ to $A$ can be ignored and what we have left is exactly an instance of the original question, maybe this is what you denoted by $2|A|+1\rightarrow |B|$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I meant $2|A|+1\to2|B|$ (that is, an instance of the ordinary pigeonhole principle). The mapping takes $2x+i$ to $2y+j$ if the $i$th outgoing edge of $x\in A$ is the $j$th incoming edge of $y\in B$, assuming $a$ is the vertex in $A$ with the largest label.

Comment: Blimey, I think you are absolutely right. Then this means that the original question is in PPP, in fact even PPAD for invertible mappings.

Comment: How does that put the original question in PPP? $\;$

Comment: If the original mapping $f$ is invertible, then you can just make $t-1$ copy of each output and define $g(x)$ to map to the $\min(i,t-1)$-th copy if there exactly $i-1$ other $x'<x$ for which $g(x')=g(x)$. This gives a map from $M$ to $(t-1)N$, so an instance of $PPP$.

Comment: @Emil: Btw, this logic also implies that if there are no one-way permutations in the strong sense that for every $f\in FP$ permutation also $f^{-1}\in FP$, then $PPAD=PPP$ (and thus also $=PPADS$).

Comment: Was "for invertible mappings" supposed to cover "in PPP" too? $\;$

Comment: @Domotorp: I'm sorry, but I don't follow the argument. How do you count how many other $x'$ there are with $g(x)=g(x')$  in polynomial time?

Comment: Aha, invertible here means we can compute the list of all preimages. (I was thinking about a function $f^{-1}$ that selects *one* preimage, which is the kind of setup I usually encounter in the context of a pigeonhole principle.) Yes, the generalized php is then in PPP. However, I wouldn’t say this answers the original question, since being given an inverse is a substantial restriction, even in the case of ordinary php (i.e., $t=2$). This is most striking for the *weak* php, say $2N\to N$: it has a randomized polynomial-time solution if given an inverse, but if not, it can find collisions ...

Comment: ... of hashing functions, and factorize integers.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree that the original question is not answered yet.